# I want to print an element from an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, int, element

in my program I want the user to be able to print an element from an array. This is how far I've and I can't think of what to put next?

```
public void viewClub() { 

System.out.println("Please enter the name of the country whose details you would like to see");

    String Name = input.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < countryList.size(); i++) {

        Country x = countryList.get(i);

        if (Name.equalsIgnoreCase(x.getName())) {


        }
```

Comment: You wrote all that code, but you don't know how to print a string?

Comment: You're not using an array anywhere in your code. Note that `ArrayList` is not an array.

Comment: public void viewClub() { 
   
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the team whose statistics you would like to see");

        String Name = input.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < clubList.size(); i++) {

            FootballClub x = clubList.get(i);

            if (Name.equalsIgnoreCase(x.getName())) {
                System.out.println(i);
               
            }

Answer (score 0):

You anyways have x.getName in which x points to ith element of the array. So even if you just do a sys out for

```
x.getName()
```

you will get the value.

Hope this be of some help

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to output the details of a country that the user inputs. To do this, you will need a function in your country class that returns a string containing the details of that country:

```
System.out.println(x.getCountryDetails());
```

You don't want to output the name, because the user already knows that.

After you find the country, you should break out of your loop, to stop further processing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < countryList.size(); i++)
{
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(countryList.get(i).getname()))
    {
        System.out.println(countryList.get(i).getCountryDetails());
        break; //Exit the for loop because you found the specified country
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly you take a array in your program, then by using buffered input streams or any other take the input from the user, store it into the array and then print the array index which contain the values